# Why np.concatenate changes dimension

Tags: python, numpy

In the following program, I am trying to understand how np.concatenate command works. After accessing each row of the array a by for loop, when I concatenate along row axis I expect a 2-dimensional array having the shape of `(5,5)` but it changes.

I want to have the same dimension `(5,5)` after concatenation. How can I do that?

I tried to repeat the above method for the 2-dimensional array by storing them in a list `[(2,5),(2,5),(2,5)]`. At the end when I concatenate it gives me the shape of `(6,5)` as expected but in the following case, it is different.

```
a = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)


ind =[0,1,2,3,4]
list=[]
for i in ind:
    list.append(a[i])

new= np.concatenate(list, axis=0)
print(list)
print(len(list))
print(new)
print(new.shape)
```

This gives the following results for `new`:

```
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24]
```

and for `new.shape`:

```
(25,)
```

Comment: Firstly, don't use `list` as a name because that's a builtin. Second, it looks like you just need `np.array(lst)`, which will give an array of `(5, 5)`. I'm not sure why you're using `concatenate`; `np.array(lst)` gives the same output as `a = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)`

Comment: You should add the output to your question. Put it into a code block to preserve formatting.

Comment: But after concatination when I print new it gives me a shape of (25,) where as I want it to be (5,5). I want that after concatination  2nd row appears below first row.

Comment: `np.concatenate` is similar to `+` for python lists (but can work on any axis of the input arrays), You want `np.array(list)` or `np.vstack(list)`.

Comment: Desired output is same as a having shape of (5,5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To preface this you really should not be using `concatenate` here.

***Setup***

```
a = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
L = [i for i in a]
```

You're question asks:

> Why is `np.concatenate` changing dimension?

It's *not* changing dimension, it is doing exactly what it is supposed to based on the input you are giving it.  [From the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

> Join a sequence of arrays along an existing axis

When you pass your list to `concatenate`, don't think of it as passing a `(5, 5)` list, think of it as passing 5 `(5,)` shape arrays, which are getting joined along axis `0`, which will intuitively produce a `(25,)` shape output.

Now this behavior also gives insight on how to work around this.  If passing 5 `(5,)` shape arrays produces a `(25,)` shape output, we just need to pass `(1, 5)` shape arrays to produce a `(5, 5)` shape output.  We can accomplish this by simply adding a dimension to each element of `L`:

```
np.concatenate([[i] for i in L])
```

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

*However*, the *much* better way to approach this is to simply use `stack`, `vstack`, etc..

```
>>> np.stack(L)
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])

>>> np.vstack(L)    
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```